# Can a filestream data change while reading a file twice.

Tags: c#, filestream

I am using filestreams to both write a file and calcuate a file's signature. If the signature doesn't match the file the whole process can fail badly and data can be lost. If i use the same filestream to write, then rewind it, can i get different data the 2nd time i read from the stream if the file is being actively modified? I really need to ensure that i am looking at the exact same data stream as when i wrote the file.

```
using (Stream newFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\somefile.txt", 
FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    // read from filestream to write to new location

    newFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // read from filestream to calculate signature. 
}
```

Comment: Not with FileShare.Read, because no other process can write to the file while it's open. But why don't you read and calculate at the same time, without reading the file twice?

Comment: How would you do that? Read a chunk of bytes process them, then repeat?